# Laravel - Test Edit Form with Value tag

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, laravel-5.6

I'm using Laravel 5.6 to develop a website.

Currently, I want to write a test codes for the website. I'm also new to building a website in general and this is learning curve for me to learn what I'm doing wrong.

I created a Profile based on a User model and the Profile should only be editable by the authenticated User only.

The form is actually working without errors on the browser side but once i run phpunit, it will fail.

**Test Script:**

```
/** @test */
public function an_authenticated_user_can_view_the_profile_page()
{
    // Generate fake instance of authenticated user
    $this->be($user = factory('App\User')->create());

    // Will get the URL
    $response = $this->get('/profile/'.$user->name);

    // Check whether the string exists
    $response->assertSee('Personal details for '.$user->name);
}
```

**Controller:**

```
class ProfileController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function show(User $user)
    {
        return view('user.profiles.show', compact('user'));
    }

    public function update(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate(request(), [
            'company' => 'required',
            'street' => 'required',
            'city' => 'required',
            'zip_code' => 'required',
            'state' => 'required',
            'country' => 'required',
            'phone' => 'required',
        ]);

        $profile = \Auth::user()->profile;

        $profile->update($request->all());

        return back()->with('success', 'Profile updated!');
    }
}
```

**View:**

```
<div class="heading">
    <h3 class="text-uppercase">Personal details for {{ $user->name }}</h3>
</div>

<form method="POST" action="/profile">

{{method_field('PATCH')}}

{{csrf_field()}}

    <input type="hidden" value="{{ $user->profile->id }}" name="id">

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="company">Company</label>
            <input id="company" type="text" class="form-control" name="company" value="{{ $user->profile->company }}" required>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Image of the commented out Form test:
[Commented Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjj5y.png)

Image of the not commented Form test:
[Not commented Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvDMC.png)

I am rather confused why my test is failing once I insert the form with a value tag. If i commented out the form or just remove the value tag, the test will pass.

Been searching for the few days and still can't find the right answer to this. Am i using the right Assertion? What am I missing here? Any inputs will help me to further understand this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. It was actually the factory that I've created.

In the User model, every registration leads to creating an empty Profile.

This is the new way of how I write the test script:

```
/** @test */
public function an_authenticated_user_can_view_the_profile_page()
{
    //Generate a fake profile
    $profile = factory('App\Profile')->create();

    // Assign it to the user
    $user = $profile->user;

    // Authenticate the user
    $this->be($user);

    // Will get the URL
    $response = $this->get('/profile/'.$user->name);

    // Check whether the string exists
    $response->assertSee('Personal details for '.$user['name']);
}
```